# how to keep mark dynamically check boxes values after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, checkbox

im working on dynamically check boxes and checkbox values are fetching from mysql database and check box values are also store into db table after form submitted here everything working fine

problem is that when i click checkbox then all checkbox values are marked and checked but i want when i click single checkbox value then function should marked or checked that value that checked and shouldn't marked all checkbox values?

**mysql database query**

```
 function select_user_permissions(){

 global $data;

 $result=db_rows(

 "SELECT * FROM `{$data['DbPrefix']}permissions` order by pid");

 return $result;

 }

function select_user_id_permissions(){

global $data;
$adminid=$_REQUEST['userid'];
$result=("SELECT * FROM `{$data['DbPrefix']}user_permission` 
where permuserid='$adminid' ");


return $result;
}



$post['select_user']=select_user_permissions();
$post['select_user_perm']=select_user_id_permissions();


<form name="my_form" method=post>

<? 
foreach($post['select_user'] as $key => $values){
?>
<input type=checkbox name=userperm[] value=<?=$values['pid']?> 
<?php if($post['userperm']) { echo " checked=checked'"; } ?>>

<label for="<?=$values['permname']?>"><?=$values['permname']?></label>
<? } ?>

<input class=submit type=submit name=send value="SAVE CHANGES">
</form>
```

**here i got solution for it**

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js'>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function Check(chk)
{
if(document.myform.Check_ctr.checked==true){
for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
chk[i].checked = true ;
}else{

for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
chk[i].checked = false ;
}
}

// End -->
</script>

<?php
echo "the following values have been checked: ";
$checked="";
$a = array();
if(isset($_POST["userperm"])) {
    foreach($_POST["userperm"] as $j=>$i) {
        $checked .= ($checked==""?"":",") . "checkbox" . $i;
        array_push($a, $i);
    }
}
echo $checked;

function was_checked($i,$a) {
if(in_array($i, $a)===true) {
return "checked='checked'";
return "";
}
}
?>

<? 
foreach($post['select_user'] as $key => $values){

?>
<input type=checkbox name=userperm[] value=<?=$values['pid']?>
<?=was_checked($values['pid'],$a)?>>
<label for="<?=$values['permname']?>"><?=$values['permname']?></label>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create an array
$arrUserDtls["userid"] = {user_permission_name}.

instead of

```
<?php if($post['userperm']) { echo " checked=checked'"; } ?>>
```

Please use this:

```
<?php if($arrUserDtls[$values] == $values['permname']) { echo " checked=checked'"; } ?>>
```

Comment: but problem is that after form submit all checkbox values marked and checked? i want only mark that values which is mark or checked...

Comment: $arrUserDtls array should contain only userid & related permission name so that when the condition satisfied "$arrUserDtls[$values] == $values['permname']" it shows checked

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the logic, but you're missing a single quote after `checked=`

```
<?php if($post['userperm']) { echo " checked='checked'"; } ?>>
```

Also, I'm afraid `for="<?=$values['permname']?>"` will be treated as a string, not code.

```
<label <?php echo "for='" . $values['permname'] . "'"; ?>><?=$values['permname']?></label>
```